# Concatenating a String to build a file path

Tags: c#, .net, string

Very simple concept but I am striking out here.
I am trying to build a simple file explorer like Path but I can't seem to get it straight.

The method to build the Path is:

```
private string BuildFullPath(List<Project> Children)
    {
        string path = string.Empty;
        foreach(Project project in Children)
        {
            if (this.ParentFolder == null)
            {
                path = this.Name;
            }
            else 
            {
                path += this.ParentFolder.Name + " > " + this.Name;
            }
        }
        return path;
    }
```

And the fake data is

```
Projects = new ObservableCollection<Project>();
        Project parentOne = new Project("Apple", true, null);
        Project parentTwo = new Project("Samsung", true, null);
        Project parentThree = new Project("Google", true, null);
        Project parentFour = new Project("Amazon", true, null);

        Project parentOneChildOne;
        parentOneChildOne = new Project("Mac", true, parentOne);
        Project parentOneChildTwo;
        parentOneChildTwo = new Project("iPhone", true, parentOne);
        Project parentOneChildThree;
        parentOneChildThree = new Project("iPad", true, parentOne);
        parentOne.Children.Add(parentOneChildOne);
        parentOneChildOne.Children.Add(new Project("MacBook", true, parentOneChildOne));
        parentOneChildOne.Children.Add(new Project("MacBook Pro", true, parentOneChildOne));
        parentOneChildOne.Children.Add(new Project("MacBook Air", true, parentOneChildOne));
        projects.Add(parentOne);
```

So the path for MacBook Pro should be Apple -> Mac- >MacBook -> MacBook Pro and the path for Mac should just be Apple -> Mac but can't seem to shake it.

Comment: What does your project class look like?  I have a way better idea

Comment: in your `Apple -> Mac- >MacBook -> MacBook Pro` example I don't see you trying to add a `-` anywhere. Please show the exact string output you are trying to get and what you are actually getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the line of this....

```
private string BuildFullPath(Project project)
    {
        string path = string.Empty;
        while(project != null) {
           if(path != string.Empty)
               path = "->" + path;
           path = project.Name + path
           project = project.ParentFolder;
        }
        return path;
    }
```